# Is there a way to compare only particular groups in anova model test using statsmodels in Python similar to SAS's CONTRAST

Tags: python, sas, statsmodels, anova, patsy

In SAS there is CONTRAST statement that allows the comparison of only particular groups/means based on the model constructed with all data.  In SAS **L** vector is used for such operations. https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/statug/15.2/statug_glm_syntax06.htm Is there the same/similar functionality in python's statsmodels/patsy?

my patsy formula looks like that:

`model = ols("value ~ C(variety, Sum)", data=df).fit()`

the data I have looks like that:

```
--value--variety
    1    var 1
    32.  var 2
    ...
```

Comment: Results methods `wald_test` (or `f_test` in linear models) can be used for joint testing of user specified linear hypotheses. I guess that's closest.

Comment: for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48097949/statsmodels-patsy-hypothesis-testing-categorical-variable-in-constraint-c

Comment: @Josef Thank you a lot for your response. Could please tell me what would comparing of three groups would look like, let's say var 1, var 2, var 4, let's imaging that we have 7 varieties: var 1, 2, 3,4 ... ?